# How to get html source code of a web page

Tags: curl, web-scraping, browser, elinks

I was using **curl** to *scrape* html code from a certain website. then they changed their server settings and curl no longer can get the page content giving error code 1020
then I changed my script to use **elinks**.

but again they are now using cloudflare and **elinks** no longer works (only in this particular website). and it gives the same error code 1020.

is there any command line or option to use other browsers (firefox,chromium, google-chrome...) and get the page html in a terminal ?

Comment: I tested puppeteer just now and same thing: error 1020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write scripts for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), here is a small example using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) library. It logs page source code after the page is loaded in a headless (invisible) Chrome, with dynamic content generated by page scripts:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto('https://example.org/');
  console.log(await page.content());

} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same error code 1020 as curl and elinks. either this is a misconfiguration on their part or they are really paranoid . other websites even with cloudflare work just fine

Comment: @NeoMosaid Sometimes launching the browser in headful mode can help. I've edited the second line of code for this. Also you can try [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth).

Comment: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module . sorry I've never used nodejs before

Comment: @NeoMosaid Try to change script file extension to `.mjs` — then Node.js will interpret it as a module with modern syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I bring to your attention the code and libraries that bypass protection cloudflare:

Libs:

```
npm i puppeteer-extra puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth puppeteer
```

nodejs:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer')

const link = 'https://www.g2.com/'

const getHtmlThoughCloudflare = async (url) => {
  puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())
  const result = await puppeteer
    .launch({ headless: true })
    .then(async (browser) => {
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.goto(url)
      const html = await page.content()
      await browser.close()
      return html
    })

  console.log(` HTML: ${result}`)
  return result // html
}

getHtmlThoughCloudflare(link)
```